# instance creating instances

Tags: c++, instance

How can I create an instance which creates as many instances as I want?

I think I have to create a class `Manager` for example and inside that class with an aggregation relationship to create the class name `salary` and `bottles`.

I want to create an instance of `Manager` which creates as many instances of bottle and salary I want. How can I do that?

Comment: You write a class that can create instances of another class.  There's nothing special about it.

Comment: Google Factory pattern, factory method, and builder pattern.

Comment: Google,and try yourself first!

Answer (score 0):

It's called a factory and it looks something like:

```
class Factory {
    Product create(int n);
    // ...
}

class Product {
    // ...
}

class Prod1 : public Product {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    Factory factory = Factory();
    Product prod[10] = factory.create(10);
    // ...
```

with `create` simply returning a `Product` object of some derived type.  Of course, there's usually some context passed into the `Factory::create` function to hint at the type of `Product` you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use pointers. You can have a pointer which points to as many instances as you want and new them whenever you want.